# Angular JS show input when radio checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show

I have a javascript array like so:

```
$scope.quantityMachines = [
  { 'snippet' : 'One' },
  { 'snippet' : 'Two' },
  { 'snippet' : 'Three or more',
    'extraField' : true },
  { 'snippet' : 'Not sure, need advice' }
];
```

Then I have a list of radio buttons generated by Angular JS using the array:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="quantity in quantityMachines">
    <input type="radio" id="quantityMachines{{$index}}" name="quantityMachines" value="{{quantity.snippet}}" ng-model="howMany" />
    <label for="quantityMachines{{$index}}">{{quantity.snippet}}</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works. In the array there is an `extraField` with value `true` in one of the indexes. I need Angular to show an extra input field when a radio button with the `extraField` setting is checked. The array may change to have more than one index with the `extraField` value.

So the extra field would look something like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="extraInfo" ng-show="howMany" />
```

Other than knowing to use `ng-show`, I'm not sure what would be the correct way to do this. The above example of course does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-if` and `ng-show` combination and a scope variable to keep track what is selected. ng-if will make sure the textbox is not added unwantedly to the DOM and ng-show to show and hide as the radio gets toggled.

In your input:-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="extraInfo" ng-if="quantity.extraField" ng-show="option.selected === howMany" />
```

and in your Radio add `ng-click="option.selected=quantity.snippet"`

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="quantity in quantityMachines">
    <input type="radio" id="quantityMachines{{$index}}" name="quantityMachines" value="{{quantity.snippet}}" ng-model="howMany" ng-click="option.selected=quantity.snippet"/>
    <label for="quantityMachines{{$index}}">{{quantity.snippet}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="extraInfo" ng-if="quantity.extraField" ng-show="option.selected === howMany" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

and add in your controller:-

```
$scope.option = { selected:'none'};
```

**[Bin](http://jsbin.com/yepezoyu/1/edit)**

You could even use `howMany` to track what was selected except that you need to set it as a property to an object on the scope (Since ng-repeat creates its own child scope and proto inheritance comes to play).

So in your radio just add `ng-model="option.howMany"`, in your controller add `$scope.option = { };` and in the text box `ng-if="quantity.extraField" ng-show="quantity.snippet === option.howMany"`

**[Bin](http://jsbin.com/yepezoyu/1/edit)**

Comment: Yeh that's the ticket!

Comment: @Cooper If howmany is bound only once for the list then you can just use that like this:- http://jsbin.com/yepezoyu/1/edit

Comment: I wonder is there a way to move the text input out of the repeat loop so it can sit underneath the entire list? It breaks the code when I move it out at the moment.

Comment: Amazing! Wish I could give you more up votes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If only you had a plunker...without that try this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="quantity in quantityMachines">
    <input type="radio" id="quantityMachines{{$index}}" name="quantityMachines" 
        value="{{quantity.snippet}}" ng-model="howMany" />
    <label for="quantityMachines{{$index}}">{{quantity.snippet}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="extraInfo" **ng-if="quantity.extraField"** />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems to generate the input but I need it to only show the new input when the related radio button is checked.

Comment: Yup. @PSL's answer will work fine. I wonder why ng-show ? Could'nt ng-if="quantity.extraField && option.selected === howMany" suffice along with the ng-click ?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/biwah/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="quantity in quantityMachines">
    <input type="radio" id="quantityMachines{{$index}}" name="quantityMachines" value="{{quantity.snippet}}" ng-model="howMany" />
    <label for="quantityMachines{{$index}}">{{quantity.snippet}}</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="quantity.extraInfo" ng-show="quantity.extraField" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to show something when radio button is checked is the following:

Lets say you have a radio-group with: `ng-model="radio-values"`

To show or hide your input then depends on the values within the radio-group: `value="radio-value1"`, `value="radio-value2"`

To finally show or hide the input field (lets say you want to show something if "radio-value1" is set) you do: 
`<input ng-show="radio-values == 'radio-value1'" ...>`